# Custom UITableViewCell backgroundView & selectedBackgroundView

Tags: uitableview, uikit

I want to style a `UITableView` to look a lot like if it had the style `UITableViewStyleGrouped` but with some subtle differences (like different colors and rounded corners with a shorter radius). The rows have variable height. I want to use this custom style for most table view controllers in my app. See the Twitter, Groupon, & GitHub Issues apps for examples.

How should I do this?

I'm thinking of doing like `UITableViewStyleGrouped` does. `UITableViewStyleGrouped` sets `backgroundView` & `selectedBackgroundView` both to instances of `UIGroupTableViewCellBackground` (a subclass of `UIView`). `UIGroupTableViewCellBackground` is a delegate of its layer and implements `drawLayer:` to set its layer's contents to a `CGImageRef`.

1. I'm pretty sure Apple creates this `CGImageRef` according to [Quartz 2D Programming Guide : Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE), which also suggests considering using `CGLayer` instead of drawing to a bitmap graphics context. Which is better for this application?
2. Also, the first cell of a `UITableViewStyleGrouped` table view adds a shadow with rounded-corners to its top using `UIImageView` (It sets it to a resizable (width-wise) `UIImage` with a translucent PNG file.) Why does it do that? Doesn't this slow scrolling? Why doesn't it just draw this to the `CGImageRef` for the first cell? Maybe the decrease in performance wasn't significant and it was easier to get the cell to look correct with an image. I saved the cell's `CGImageRef` to disk and opened it with Preview. It still has rounded corners. This overlaid view just adds the top shadow.

   Below is a screenshot of running the Core Graphics Instruments tool on my device with "Color Blended Layers" selected for a `UITableViewStyleGrouped` table view. You can see that the shadow at the top is blended. And, it looks like there's some blending going on in the last cell too.

   [image]

   [image]

   With the third cell selected (no blending). Selecting the first or last cell acts the same but doesn't get rid of the already blended overlaid views.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can count the number of rows being drawn and set the image as background for individual cell.

What you have to do is

```
cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_pressed.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
```

use this method to set the background image

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{      

      &&&&


     if((indexPath.row)==0)  
         // set image upper corner image here

     else if (indexPath.row==1)  
        //set normal image here

     else if (indexPath.row==YourArray)
        // also set the lower corner round image in the last low, which can be calculated by comparing indexpath.row to the mutablearray/array

}
```

You can also apply one condition in before the &&& part to apply a different image which has both upper and lower corners round in case array.count == 1