# Does CALayer derive its contents?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

After investigating [Custom UITableViewCell backgroundView & selectedBackgroundView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314860/custom-uitableviewcell-backgroundview-selectedbackgroundview), I noticed that each layer of `backgroundView` & `selectedBackgroundView` (of each cell of a grouped table view) has a `CGImageRef` as its contents.

Must Apple be creating each `CGImageRef` and explicitly setting the contents of each layer?

Comment: It is an implementation detail. Why is it important to you? What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `UIGroupTableViewCellBackground` is its layer's delegate and sets its layer's `contents` in `displayLayer:`. I figured this out by creating `MyLayer : CALayer` with a `setContents:` method, in which I put a breakpoint, and implementing `+[UIGroupTableViewCellBackground layerClass]` to return `[MyLayer class]`. Then, I inspected the backtrace when the breakpoint was hit.